# Displaying only some options in argparse

Tags: python

I have this code below

```
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Intro', add_help=False)
parser.add_argument('--help', action='help', help='My Help')
parser.add_argument('--master', default='abc', help='yadayada ydad', metavar='')
parser.add_argument('--slave', help='yadayada ydad', metavar='')

args = parser.parse_args()
arg_dict = vars(args)

print(arg_dict)
```

The output I want to achieve when I invoke this is

```
{'master': 'abc'}
```

Instead of

```
{'master': 'abc', 'slave': None}
```

(I would like to see something like above only when, I pass explicit arguments to slave `./test.py --slave abc`)

Comment: you can test the key in `arg_dict` and only print if not `slave`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Shawn. I was wondering if there was something more elegant built into add_argument function.

Comment: Are slave and master mutually exclusive?

Comment: yes @StephenRauch

Comment: @StephenRauch I might be wrong, I feel that my question is slightly different.

Comment: Can you state how they differ?

Comment: @StephenRauch you are right. I am sorry, should have read the answers more carefully.